# Can I count item in firestore using php

Tags: php, firebase

I want to count all items I have in the database can I use something instead of that

```
 public static function count($column, $value)
    {
        $data = self::$db->collection("problems");
        $query = $data->where($column, '=', $value);
        $documents = $query->documents();
        $total = 0;
        foreach ($documents as $document) {
            if ($document->exists()) {
                $total++;
            }
        }
        return $total;
    }
```

Comment: While you *can* do something along those lines, it can get very expensive very quickly (and slow) because you're having to read in every document to then count it. A better and more performant strategy is to keep another collection that maintains the current count of the collection you want a count of. When something is added, increment the count; when removed decrement the count. Then you only ever need to read 1 document to know the count of the collection.

Comment: thank you <3 It helps me to figure out what I should do

Comment: how about aggregation query? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries#dart